# Strange type-related error

Tags: haskell

I wrote following program:

```
isPrime x = and [x `mod` i /= 0 | i <- [2 .. truncate (sqrt x)]]

primes = filter isPrime [1 .. ]
```

it should construct list of prime numbers. But I got this error:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 7/main.hs, interpreted )

7/main.hs:3:16:
    Ambiguous type variable `a' in the constraints:
      `Floating a' arising from a use of `isPrime' at 7/main.hs:3:16-22
      `RealFrac a' arising from a use of `isPrime' at 7/main.hs:3:16-22
      `Integral a' arising from a use of `isPrime' at 7/main.hs:3:16-22
    Possible cause: the monomorphism restriction applied to the following:
      primes :: [a] (bound at 7/main.hs:3:0)
    Probable fix: give these definition(s) an explicit type signature
                  or use -XNoMonomorphismRestriction
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

If I specify signature for isPrime function explicitly:

```
isPrime :: Integer -> Bool
isPrime x = and [x `mod` i /= 0 | i <- [2 .. truncate (sqrt x)]]
```

I can't even compile isPrime function:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( 7/main.hs, interpreted )

7/main.hs:2:45:
    No instance for (RealFrac Integer)
      arising from a use of `truncate' at 7/main.hs:2:45-61
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (RealFrac Integer)
    In the expression: truncate (sqrt x)
    In the expression: [2 .. truncate (sqrt x)]
    In a stmt of a list comprehension: i <- [2 .. truncate (sqrt x)]

7/main.hs:2:55:
    No instance for (Floating Integer)
      arising from a use of `sqrt' at 7/main.hs:2:55-60
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Floating Integer)
    In the first argument of `truncate', namely `(sqrt x)'
    In the expression: truncate (sqrt x)
    In the expression: [2 .. truncate (sqrt x)]
Failed, modules loaded: none.
```

Can you help me understand, why am I getting these errors?

Comment: My guess is the truncate & sqrt. Does replacing truncate (sqrt x) by x work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your problem lies in the call `sqrt x`.  To see why, let's check the type of `isPrime` in GHCi:

```
Prelude> let isPrime x = and [x `mod` i /= 0 | i <- [2 .. truncate (sqrt x)]]
Prelude> :t isPrime
isPrime :: (Integral a, Floating a, RealFrac a) => a -> Bool
```

This tells us that the input to `isPrime` may be of any type which as an instance of *all three* specified type classes.  In other words, a number which is simultaneously an integer and a real floating point number.  While in principle one *could* declare such a type, it doesn't make much sense; and in fact, no such type does exist.

Now this explains both of your errors.  The first error is saying that `isPrime` is too polymorphic without a type signature.  The [monomorphism restriction](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monomorphism_restriction) says (roughly) that if you defined a value via a pattern match (such as `f =` or `Just x =`, but not `g y =`), it must not be polymorphic in typeclasses.  Thus, since you don't specify a type signature for `primes`, it infers the type `primes :: (Integral a, RealFrac a, Floating a) => [a]`, and then complains since it's typeclass polymorphic.

The second error comes from the set of the three typeclass constraints you have imposed.  `mod` says that `x` must be of a type which is an instance of `Integral`; `sqrt` says that its input must be of a type which is an instance of `Floating`; and `truncate` says that the result of `sqrt` (which has the same type as its input) must have a type which is an instance of `RealFrac`.  Since these are all used to fulfill identical type variables, `x` must have all these types at once, and `Integer` is neither an instance of `Floating` nor of `RealFrac`.  Consequently, when you specify that `isPrime :: Integer -> Bool`, you get an error, because `Integer` needs to be an instance of `Floating`, but isn't.  To solve this problem, we can do a [Hoogle](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) search for [a conversion function of type `(Integral a, Floating b) => a -> b`](http://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?q=%28Integral+a%2C+Floating+b%29+%3D%3E+a+%2D%3E+b).  Sure enough, Hoogle comes up with the more general `fromIntegral :: (Integral a, Num b) => a -> b`; inserting that before the `x` in the argument to `sqrt` will solve your problems, since you will only ever treat `x` as an instance of `Integral`.  That gives you:

```
-- The one other change I made: only positive numbers are prime, and 1 is not a
-- prime.
isPrime :: Integral i => i -> Bool
isPrime x | x <= 1    = False
          | otherwise = and [ x `mod` i /= 0
                              | i <- [2..truncate . sqrt $ fromIntegral x] ]

primes :: [Integer]
primes = filter isPrime [2..]
```

Note that, thanks to the monomorphism restriction, you will still need to give `primes` a type signature!  But it's probably a good idea to anyway.

Answer (score 4):

> isPrime x = and [x `mod` i /= 0 | i <- [2 .. truncate (sqrt (fromIntegral x))]]

You're missing a conversion from Integral types to Floating types in the argument for sqrt.